# Edit virtual host file using php

Tags: apache-http-server, php

I have a php application and somethings related to the application need changes to vhost.conf file.

Presently i'm making the changes manually. But i would like to automate it using a php script.

Is this advisable? I want to know the security complications involved.

Comment: Seems like quite a hack. Not really recommended since your app needs permissions to otherwise root-only scripts. Plus you'd need to reload the server too. What changes do you have to make so often? What's the real issue?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can create a file as a config(file) and use the include directive in your vhost.conf to include this file, see http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#include

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use the [Config](http://pear.php.net/package/Config) PEAR package to edit the files. Of course you are opening a major breach in your server's security, so you'll have to be extra careful about what you allow and must never write any user-provided string to that file (don't think any filtering you apply is smarter than the hacker, even if input is provided by yourself - I'm thinking about [XSS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) and [CRSF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Csrf) here).